# Oracle Sql / PL Sql - Group and Order the result based on identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where i have list of students information like.

[image]

i want the result where i will get one student from each class and sequence continue.

like
[image]

Can any help me in finding the solution for this?

Comment: You've posted a screenshot of data that shows **multiple** students in each class (in both screenshots); it doesn't show you "getting one student from each class". Please clarify (and don't post screenshots). Post a DBFiddle or SQLFiddle instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an analytic function like `dense_rank` to order by position within class; where that function is partitioned by class and ordered by... something, which can only really be the student or their marks:

```
select class, student, marks
from your_table
order by dense_rank() over (partition by class order by student), class
```

| CLASS | STUDENT | MARKS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 |
| 2 | B | 11 |
| 3 | F | 54 |
| 4 | G | 55 |
| 1 | C | 20 |
| 2 | H | 30 |
| 1 | D | 40 |
| 1 | E | 45 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=79728b708a18eed3b17c7e27d3722f86) showing both possible orders for fun.